# What are the odds of two values occurring in a specific order.

Tags: probability

So, I have a playlist including 33 songs by one of my favorite artists. Now I know that the "shuffle" feature isn't truly random. But, upon listening to the playlist, two songs "Here We Go" and "Here we go again" appeared consecutively in the playlist.

My question is...what are the odds of those two songs appearing in that order? (Position of the other songs doesn't matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to happen you need

- "Here we go" not to be the last song . . . . . probability $\frac{32}{33}$; and then
- "Here we go again" to be in the following position . . . . . probability $\frac{1}{32}$.

So the probability is
$$\frac{32}{33}\times\frac{1}{32}=\frac{1}{33}\ .$$
To put it in perspective: if you listened to the same playlist once a day, you would expect this to happen about once a month.  It's not all that unusual.

Comment: How very mediocre and lame then.  I'll accept your answer when it allows me to do so.

Comment: That's life... some things are not as surprising as they seem.  If you want to see a probability question that is a bit more surprising, check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: Oddly enough, I've been to that page for a completely separate reason (I was looking up the birthday attack on hashing), and I do find it interesting! 50% probability with only 23 people. o.O